Limit Fetched Items on Eager Load in Laravel
I read that you can limit items fetched by eager loaded relationships but I can't get this code below to work yet.
Category::whereHas(
            'subCategories',
            fn($query) => $query->with([
                'items',
                fn($q) => $q->limit(10)
            ])
        )->latest()->get()

I want to fetch at most 10 items per each subcategory if the subcategory exist. At the moment, the code above fetches all items under each subcategory.
TABLE
Category
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('icon');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Subcategory
 Schema::create('sub_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignIdFor(Category::class)->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('image_url')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Item
 Schema::create('items', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignIdFor(SubCategory::class)->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->double('amount');
        $table->text('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('image_url');
        $table->integer('hits');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Please, someone should point me in the right direction.

Thanks for the response. No, it doesn't.

Did you try $q->skip(0)->take(10) instead of $q->limit(10)?

Which version of Laravel are you running? I believe L11 has native support for limiting the number of eagerly loaded results per parent.

@Bennett Yes, it does and this is how it ought to be done.

I am assuming this is your data model, based on your specification that categories have subcategories (assuming it's a parent-child relation) and subcategories have items:
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INT,
    name TEXT,
    parent_id INT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE items (
    id INT,
    name TEXT,
    category_id INT);

Whenever I have to write a more complex query builder I always write it out in SQL first, and this might be what you want to achieve:
-- Select all items related to the found subcategories
-- with a maximum item count per subcategory.
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY id) AS nr
    FROM items
    WHERE category_id IN (2, 3, 4)
) AS sq1
WHERE nr < 10

After some experimenting here is what I put together:
$categories = Category::whereHas('subCategories')
->with('items', function ($query) {
    $query->fromSub(function ($query) {
        $query->select('*')
        ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_id ORDER BY id) AS nr')
        ->from('items');
    }, 'items')
    ->where('nr', '<', '10');
})
->latest()
->get();

A ROW_NUMBER is added to each item in a sub query which is later used in ->where('nr', '<', '10') to limit the amount of items retrieved per category_id.
To use this subquery the fromSub function is used (which seems to be less popular because I can't find it in the official documentation). The subquery has to be named 'items', otherwise the eager loading fails with an error Unknown column 'items.category_id'
UPDATE: Slightly different answer after receiving extra information about datamodel:
$categories = Category::with('subCategories')
    ->with('subCategories.items', function ($query) {
        $query->fromSub(function ($query) {
            $query->select('*')
            ->selectRaw('ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sub_category_id ORDER BY id) AS nr')
            ->from('items');
        }, 'items')
    ->where('nr', '<', '10');
    })
    ->latest()
    ->get();

The above query builder makes for this SQL:
select * from categories order by created_at DESC
select * from sub_categories where sub_categories.category_id in (<whichever IDs were found in query 1>)
select * from (select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sub_category_id ORDER BY id) AS nr from items) as items where items.sub_category_id in (<whichever IDs were found in query 2>) and nr < 10


Thanks for the response. The items table doesn't have category_id, instead it has sub_category_id. Category hasMany SubCategory, and SubCategory hasMany Items.

Would you mind editing your question to include the CREATE TABLE for these two and the (I assume) pivot table? Or did you solve it yourself by now?

I have added the table design to the question.

I added to my answer. Alternatively, you could look at the Eloquent Eager Limit package which seems to add exactly the functionality you are looking for.

I will check out the edited code. That limit library has been integrated into the Laravel 11 core, that's what I trying to achieve with my code.

Awesome, I did not know that was added. Then what does $categories = Category::with(['subCategories.items' => fn ($query) => $query->limit(10)])->latest()->get(); not do that you need it to do?

I have figured it out. The mistake was mine. I wanted to show a limited number of items on the dashboard. The subcategories are more than 10. For example, 10 items per 10 subcategories results to a total of 100 items. I have to limit the number of categories to 10, then select two items per subcategories to achieve what I want. Thanks for the effort, I appreciate.
